# Does this probability distribution belong to some known family?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have encountered a probability distribution having a density $f$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ equal to
$$ \forall t>0, f(t)=\frac{1-\exp(-t)-t\exp(-t)}{t^2}.$$
Does this probability belongs to some known family of distributions?

Edit: There was a mistake in the expression of the function.

Comment: Since $f(10) < 0$, the function is not a density function.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f$ is not a density. A function is a density if it satisfies two conditions:

- $\forall t\in\mathbb R: f(t) \geq 0 $
- $\int_\mathbb R f(t)dt = 1$

Neither of these conditions is satisfied by your function, since $f(t)<0$ for $t>1$ and the integral of $f$ over $\mathbb R$ does not exist:

- near $0$, the function is bounded by $\frac{1}{t^2}$ for which the integral does not converge
- At $\infty$, the function is bounded by $\frac{1-t}{t^2}$ for which the integral does not converge.

Comment: Thank you. There was a mistake in the expression of the function.